# Ubuntu doesn't suspend or shutdown

Tags: suspend, shutdown

I'm new in ubuntu world....

My “Ubuntu” is not shutting down properly. When I order the shut down command, the system does the Log off, instead of Shutting down. It only accepts my command to shut down when I am on the LOG OFF display mode.
When I close the laptop “cap” to put it to “sleep mode”, the system does it; but when I try to activate it again, the system reboot and it gives an “Ubuntu Internal Error”.

Thks!!!!

Comment: Please do the following and [edit] your question accordingly: 1st Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in. 2nd Execute `sudo service lightdm stop` and then `sudo shutdown -h now`. Does it shut down? Are there any messages shown? You can disable the shutdown splash with F12. Also have a look into the file `/var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Could you please fix your grammar so people can better understand what you're saying?

Comment: Does "restarts the session" mean it is restarting the X ession only, like when you log out and log in again? Or does it mean the computer reboots?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Open a file /etc/default/grub (as root), using this command:

  ```
  $ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```
- And, edit this file

  ```
  Change the line with:

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

  to:

  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"
  ```
- Run update-grub (as root)

  ```
  $ sudo update-grub
  ```

Now, check is it works on not.

If above solution not works, then try this also but before that reset the above edited file:

- Change the last line of the file `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh` from `pm-suspend` to `pm-suspend --quirk-radeon-off`.(Edit this file as `root`)